# Php loop to create variables

Tags: php, loops, variables

I have a list of variables i need to create like so:

```
$meta_2_length = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-2-length', true );
$meta_2_loft = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-2-loft', true );
$meta_2_lie = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-2-lie', true );
$meta_2_bounce = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-2-bounce', true );
```

I need to make these for the numbers 2 - 14 so I figured the best way would be a loop. I am new to php but want to write as clean as possible. I thought this might work:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 14; $i++) {
   ${"meta_$i_length"} = "get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-$i-length', true );";
}
```

but when it doesnt seem to be working when I `echo $meta_3_length`

Comment: Numeric variables like this are almost always wrong. This is what arrays are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array of associativer arrays.

```
$metas = array();
$id = get_the_ID();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 14; $i++) {
    $metas[] = array(
        'length' => get_post_meta($id, "meta-$i-length", true),
        'loft' => get_post_meta($id, "meta-$i-loft", true),
        'lie' => get_post_meta($id, "meta-$i-lie", true),
        'bounce' => get_post_meta($id, "meta-$i-bounce", true)
    );
}
```

Now you can do `echo $metas[3]['length'];`.

Comment: Worked perfect and clean. Also gives me a better understanding of how to set up PHP variables like i would in JS

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation for you is create an array. And give the array values in the loop.

example

```
$foo = array();    
for($i = 0; $i <= 14; $i++) {
   $foo[] = "get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-$i-length', true );";
}
```

then echo data by using the array

Comment: Why did you put the call to `get_post_meta` in quotes?

Comment: If I use this (without qoutes around `get_post_meta`) and I echo it out like `<?php if( !empty( $meta_length[3] ) ) { echo $meta_length[3];  } ?>` I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 14; $i++) {
   $varname = "meta_$i_length";
   $$varname = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-$i-length', true );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract` with an associative array:

```
$arr = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= 14; $i++) {
    $arr["meta_{$i}__length"] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "meta-{$i}-length", true);
}
extract($arr);
```

Then, you can do `echo $meta_3__length` and get the result of the function call `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "meta-3-length', true);`

I hope it helps